# Is there a way to issue http requests to a url using each of the available http methods one at a time?

Tags: php, http

Is there a way to issue http request to a particular url using each of the available http methods in order to test the response received from the request.

I need to do this in order to make sure that only the common Http methods POST, GET and HEAD work on my site and no other methods works

Comment: Please state language and platform.

Comment: I am using php (MAMP) on Mac. Apart from writing php specific code, is there any utility or tools that can be used to do the same.

Comment: Well. Yes. Just use a loop.

Comment: Why do you object to OPTIONS requests?

Comment: Oh, just noticed that you used a comment to explain you were looking for a tools recommendation. Tools recommendation comments are off-topic for Stackoverflow as they tend to attract spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your browser, but you can use various plugins to submit requests.

For **Chrome** use Advance Rest Client found in the Chrome store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US

For **Firefox**, I'd recommend RestClient:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/

Answer (score 0):

You need to test your own site? Why don't you just configure it not to accept any request methods you don't want?

In an Apache server, the [LimitExcept](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitexcept) directive is used for precisely this purpose. Put this inside your site's `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` file:

```
<LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

Comment: Testing is usually done to make sure that the configuration is correct.

Comment: Dear squeamish,

The hosting server uses Nginx and does not consider apache's .htacess files. and the hosting provider does not provide access to Nginx conf files also.